# How to send e-mail as a domain name?

Tags: networking, server, email, dns, postfix

I would like to create an ubuntu webserver ( with Postfix on it ) to send e-mails to different users from a static domain name; website.com

I do have access to the following DNS records website.com

The needed situation:

The server needs to send e-mails to customers from password@domain.com ( for forgotten e-mail delivery ), the webserver with postfix on it has a different IP Address then the main website: website.com

BTW: I cannot install postfix on the website it's server ( security reasons )

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Most information on what you are seeking to do is described in the [Postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/documentation.html). When setting up your Ubuntu server, assign it a hostname that is part of your domain: `myserver.mydomain.com`. Install Postfix and in the /etc/postfix/main.cf file, set `myorigin = $mydomain`. (Note: `$mydomain` is a Postfix wildcard that reads the `dnsdomainname` of the machine, not psudo-text for this post.)

You should not have to alter your DNS records unless you also want to receive emails through Postfix. If you wish to receive emails, add an an A record and an MX record for your Ubuntu server:

```
myserver.mydomain.com IN A 12.34.56.789    
mydomain.com IN MX 10 myserver.mydomain.com
```